# Javascript - onClick return what was clicked on

Tags: javascript

so, I have a div with stuff like `<h2>`s and `<img>`s in them, and I want it so that if a user doubleclicks on one of them (for example they double click on anything inside the `<h2></h2>` tags it will turn it into a textbox with `<h2>title</h2>` inside it...

I just can't figure out how to send to the javascript function what was double clicked on?

Comment: from a usability standpoint, double-clicking is an unexpected action in the browser.  Even with an instruction, there will most likely be discoverability issues.

Comment: if you are OK about using a jquery plugin, JEditable does exactly the same thing...http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: jQuery is good too :D i think that'll work just fine :D tyvm

Comment: Try Googling "javascript edit inline".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very bare example for *single click*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function foo(elem) {
      elem.innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="' + elem.innerHTML + '">';
  }
</script>
<h1 onClick="foo(this)">Hello</h1>
<h1 onClick="foo(this)">My</h1>
<h1 onClick="foo(this)">Friend</h1>
```

test live: http://jsfiddle.net/MsTzY/

Answer (score 2):

try if you are famous with jQuery:

```
$('#yourDiv *').dblclick(function(event)){
 alert(event.target.html());
}
```

Comment: +1 i like the jquery way better than my own example using pure JS. Neither of which are complete, though. ;-)